# Prove that $\{x\in A:P(x)\}$ is always a subset of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following,

**Proposition.** Let $A$ be a set and let $P(x)$ be a property pertaining to $x$, then $\{x\in A:P(x)\}\subseteq A$.

Here is my proof:

*proof.*

To prove $\{x\in A:P(x)\}\subseteq A$, we need to show that $\forall y$, $y\in\{x\in A:P(x)\}\implies y\in A$. Now suppose $y\in\{x\in A:P(x)\}$. By definition this means $(y\in A$ and $P(y)$ is true). We divide into cases. For the case $y\in A$, we have either $P(y)$ to be true or false. If $P(y)$ is true, then $y\in A\land P(y)$ is true and therefore the implication $y\in\{x\in A:P(x)\}\implies y\in A$ is true. If $P(y)$ is false, then the implication is vacuously true. Now suppose instead $y\notin A$. We have either $P(y)$ to be true or false. But in either case $y\notin A$, and so the implication is vacuously true. Hence $\{x\in A:P(x)\}\subseteq A$, as claimed.

is this correct?

Comment: Why are you running cases on the conjunction "and"?

Comment: If $x\in\{x\in A:(\cdots)\}$, then $x\in A$ by definition of that set doesn't matter what goes in $(\cdots)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by definition, no proof required. Let $x \in P$ be arbitrary, $x\in P \iff x\in A: P(x)$.

Hence, $P \subseteq A$. "Technically" there is a conjunction where i put the colon, but we can drop it because "P(x)" might as well be a contradiction (i.e. naive set theory).